# Chrome app context menu on webview

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there any way to enable context menus on webviews in a Chrome app? The app we have runs a webview in fullscreen mode and there doesn't seem to be a way to add to the context menu on the webview. If this is not possible, is there some way to add items to the application level menu for the app?

Comment: It seems that The "`contextMenus`" API to add custom menu items to `<webview>` is in experimental, which means it will only work in dev/canary channel of chrome: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/novVeh1nG8w

Comment: It has been added in Chrome 44+, [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-ContextMenus)